# NSMutableString doesn't get append

Tags: iphone, ios4

```
[string appendString:@""];
((appdelegete *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).salesReceipt.old = [string ];
```

I want to add all my elements in my `NSMutableString` string  whose data are getting collected. What is the best way to do it?In my appdelegate class  there is a `NSMutableString` in which I am going to store all the elements from the `NSMutableString`

Comment: could you please clarify? are you asking how to add objects to a NSMutableArray ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutabelString* string = [[NSMutabelString alloc] initWithCapacity:2]
[string appendString:@"My String "];
[string appendString:@""];
//Now you need to access your NSMutableArray from Delegate add add the string.
 NSMutableArray* myArray = ((appdelegete *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).salesReceipt.items ;
[myArray addObject:string];
```

Comment: @guy : What the type of `old` ?

Comment: old is a NSString and I am calling it after salesreceipt

Comment: @guy  : Now check answer just updated , and considering `salesReceipt` would be type of `NSMutabelArray` ..

Comment: I AM POSTING SOME MY CODE..IN MY ADDDEDELGATE.H ReceiptClass *salesReceipt;IN APPDELEGATE.M salesReceipt = [[ReceiptClass alloc]init];
    
    salesReceipt.items = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
   
    user = [[UserClass alloc ] init]; IN SIGNATURE.M[signaturestring appendString:@""];
    NSMutableArray *myarray= ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).salesReceipt ;

Comment: Just replace the belo line with your code .... **IN SIGNATURE.M**

`[signaturestring appendString:@""]; 
NSMutableArray *myarray= ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).salesReceipt.items  ;`

Comment: but how to add signaturestring into appdelegate?I need to add my signaturestring into appdelegeteclass

Comment: well its still not getting stord

Comment: @guy :could you show me how you would have declared `old` in your AppDelage ?